# Oracle import batch files within a bat file

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have to run several bat file to import mass data into Oracle. **I'd like to run only one bat file.**

The batch files are in separeted subfolders like this:

```
g:\1\import.bat
g:\2\import.bat
...
g:\n\import.bat
```

And they looks like this:

```
@echo off
REM Copyright (c) 1999-2004 by Intergraph Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
REM Use this script to create feature class tables via SQL and populate tables with SQL*Loader.
REM The GDOSYS schema is no longer created via this script. If you want metadata to be loaded,
REM GDOSYS needs to exist prior to running import. You may use Database Utilities to create GDOSYS.
REM If you are using a comma for a decimal separator, set the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter:
REM SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.
if "%1"=="" goto usage
SQLPLUS %1> @"kat_ki_vectors_epulet_i_pre.sql"
SQLLDR %1 CONTROL='kat_ki_vectors_epulet_i'
SQLPLUS %1 @"kat_ki_vectors_epulet_i_post.sql"
goto end
: usage
echo SYNTAX:  "Import username/password@ConnectString" 
echo WHERE:
echo - username/password is the Oracle user account where the data will be loaded.
echo - ConnectString is the Oracle NET string used to connect to the Oracle server.
echo See the document "Working with GeoMedia Professional" for more
information.
echo EXAMPLES:
echo Import scott/tiger@db_orcl
: end 
pause
```

I tried to run all of them with this bat file (with proper authentication):

```
call g:\1\import.bat ###/###@###.##
call g:\2\import.bat ###/###@###.##
...
call g:\n\import.bat ###/###@###.##
```

but this is what I got:

```
G:\>do_the_trick.bat
G:\>call g:\1\import.bat ###/###@###.##
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on K. Jan. 24 15:35:08 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Kapcsolódási cél:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
SP2-0310: nem lehet megnyitni a(z) "kat_ki_vectors_epulet_i_pre.sql" fájlt

"Kapcsolódási cél" ---> "Connecting target"
"nem lehet megnyitni a(z) " ---> "Can not be opened"
```

however if I run the first bat file directly

```
G:\1>import.bat ###/###@###.##
```

The import begins.

Please give me some tips to try out!

Comment: The difference is that you manually run the batch from it's subdir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch should work, and only requires to set the maximal possible number.
The batch will evaluate the current highest number.

```
@Echo off
CD /D "G:\"
:: first get the highest number increase if max > 1000
For /L %%N in (1,1,1000) Do If Exist "G:\%%N" (Set Max=%%N) Else Goto :Cont
:Cont
:: iterate through all numbered subdirs
For /L %%N in (1,1,%Max%) Do (
  Pushd "G:\%%N"
  Call import.bat ###/###@###.##
  PopD
)
```

To get **ALL** subdirs of `G:\` you could use

```
@Echo off
For /D %%A in (G:\*) Do (
  Pushd "%%~fA"
  Call import.bat ###/###@###.##  
  PopD
)
```

**EDIT** Another version which pipes an (empty) echo to import.bat so no need to do acknowlede manually. It also checks for the existence of import.bat

```
@Echo off
Set App=Import.bat
Set Cred=###/###@###.##  
For /D %%A in (G:\*) Do (
  Pushd "%%~fA"
  If Exist %APP% Echo:|Call %App% %Cred%
  PopD
)
```

Comment: Okay, I was a bit misleading I guess: the numbers in the names of the subfolders only represent that there are many subfolders. 
Their real name are alphanumeric.

But I tried your script with 3 subfolders containing the Import.bat.
g:\1\
g:\2\
g:\3\

And that is what I got:
"The system cannot find the batch label specified - Cont"

Comment: @STO Sorry my fault, simply forgot (changed above). Do you want to process all subfolders in `G:\` ?

Comment: @STO I added a version which would iterate **ALL** subdirs of `G:\`

Comment: The  2nd version runs nicely but between the two import process I have to press the any key :) because of the "pause" at the end of the import.bat files. It's not a big thing to remove the pause from the end of every import.bat, but maybe you can add something to your script that ignores this pauses.

Comment: @STO Sorry for the delay. I'll add another version which pipes an (empty) echo to import.bat so no need to do it manually. It also checks for the existence of import.bat.

Comment: Dear LotPings! This is what I need, thank you for your time!